# Converting ajax to node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I've learnt dealing with ajax calls to exchange information from the server to the browser but now I'm having big troubles converting my code to a server-side node compatible JS using http requests. I've read different tutorials but I just can't adapt them to my code.
My simple JS / jQuery function is this:

```
function ajaxCall(data, php, callback) {
    ax = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url: php,
        success: function (raw_data) {
            f = $.parseJSON(raw_data);
            callback(f);
        },
    });
}
```

And I need to convert it to a pure JS version with http requests to use with node.js. Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**: I tried and tried, but without success. Here is the code I used, I just get lots of meaningless words on my console.log, perhaps you can correct it:

*Version 1*

```
var data = {"action": "update", "tN": 2155};
var request = require("request");

request.post({
    url: 'http://example.com/PHP.php',
    data: data,
    }, function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
    }
);
```

*Version 2*

```
var request = require("request");
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://example.com/PHP.php',
    data: {"action": "update", "tN": 2155},
};    
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: EDIT: And I do _not_ want to use the jquery module in node.js (it's very problematic, especially on Windows!)

Comment: So you don't really want ajax, you just want to make a request from the server?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr2

Comment: https://github.com/request/request

Comment: If you don't want XHR but only need to make a http request look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652057/node-js-xmlhttprequest-get-header-informations

Answer (score 4):

Use `request.js`

Example:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})
```

Documentation [request.js](https://github.com/request/request)

Comment: mhh ok yes thank you, that would definitely be useful, but I'd like if possible to avoid using libraries, I thought converting that simple function may produce simple JS as well...I'm also interested in "seeing" the pure JS that does that http request, just for curiosity, if you know what I mean!

Comment: Just look code on Github : https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js